# NSString sizeWithFont forWidth returning wrong values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a weird problem. My `sizeWithFont: forWidth: lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` is returning wrong values. I have an array of strings which need to be placed in a neat "table". Cells are basically `UIView`s with `UILabel`s in them. In order to alloc-init the cell view and the label with the right frame I need to pre-compute the desired height of the cell and the total height of the wrapper view since all cells will be placed in another view. My code looks like this:

```
#define kStandardFontOfSize(x)  [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:x]

CGFloat size = 0.0f; //for computing the total size as cells will be placed in another view
items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"You have 23 new followers", @"1125 new likes", @"Successful week with 24 new Twitter followers and 60 new email subscribers", @"1125 new tickets", nil];

for (NSString *item in items)
{
    if ([item sizeWithFont:kStandardFontOfSize(16) forWidth:100 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height < 25)
        size += 70; //either the cell will be 70 (140) pixels tall or 105 (210)pixels
    else
        size += 105;
    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %@", [item sizeWithFont:kStandardFontOfSize(16) forWidth:100 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width, [item sizeWithFont:kStandardFontOfSize(16) forWidth:100 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height, item);
}
```

But the log is returning very weird values:

```
82.000000, 20.000000, You have 23 new followers
99.000000, 20.000000, 1125 new likes
70.000000, 20.000000, Successful week with 24 new Twitter followers and 60 new email subscribers
67.000000, 20.000000, 1125 new tickets
```

How is it possible that the width of "1125 new likes" is 99 and the long string is only 70? The height should definitely be greater than 20 or?

Comment: Side note - why do you create the same font 3 times for each loop iteration? Why not create the font once before the loop and use that one reference in the loop? That would be far more efficient.

Comment: The log is only temporary.

Comment: Even so, you needlessly create the same font every iteration of the loop. Do it once before the loop.

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent remark. Thank you, will fix it right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `[[NSString string] sizeWithFont:UIFont constrainedToSize:CGSize lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)]`

Comment: The important part of using this method is to pass the proper size to the `constrainedToSize:` parameter. The width should be the desired width and the height needs to be a big number. Either a number like 9999 or some maximum value you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Maister, this happens because the method `[item sizeWithFont: forWidth:100 lineBreakMode:]` is considering when the word does not fit in the line, it jump to the next.
So, the labels (100 width) will be something like that:

```
You have 23 
followers
```

while the other label can fit the whole string:

```
1125 new likes
```

Now you can see the difference between those two strings in my text (considering the max width: 100).
If you change the `lineBreakMode` to Character Wrap, it will probably give 100 to the first string and 99 to the second.

Comment: But why doesnt the height change?

Comment: This method does not do what many people think. The `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` only gives you the height of the first line after doing any wrapping or truncating.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. Any ideas how could I fulfil my original purpose then? I need to calculate the frame of the label in which the string will fit.

Comment: @Majster See the answer by Leta0n.